# Qt creator update for harmattan developement

Tags: qt, ubuntu-12.04, meego-harmattan

I am trying to update the Qt sdk for harmattan developement. This is the instruction i am following

[harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Getting_started_with_Harmattan_using_Qt_SDK_Installing_Qt_SDK_on_Linux.html](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Getting_started_with_Harmattan_using_Qt_SDK_Installing_Qt_SDK_on_Linux.html)

After succesfully installing Qt and moving to the first point of updating Qt sdk for harmattan development

> To update the Qt SDK with the MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan API target, click
>   Help on the Qt Creator top toolbar and select Start Updater. On the
>   Package manager tab, you can find the MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan API target
>   from under Qt SDK > Development Tools > Harmattan > MeeGo 1.2
>   Harmattan. You can also select other targets, such as the Harmattan
>   emulator (QEMU).

When i go to start updater -> package manager and hit next. The computer hangs(non responsive ) and after a while shows my login screen (as if it has restarted without showing any signs of restart which it normally does while restarting), once i login all my previous processes are gone including qt creator. I have no idea whats wrong here. My box is on ubuntu lts 12.04 and qt sdk is 1.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cause by a bug in the QWidgets of SDKMaintenanceTool. The workaround is start the updater from terminal with argument `-style cleanlooks`

```
~ $ /path/to/QtSDK/SDKMaintenanceTool -style cleanlooks
```